# Is there any point to using kubernetes if my app is just 1 docker file that needs to be scaled?

Tags: docker, google-app-engine

What would be the benefit of running a kubernetes cluster, instead of just spawning a load balancer that launches images of my vm+container.

Answer (score 1):

There is significant overhead deploying and managing a Kubernetes (K8s) cluster. Unless your scale is quite large, I'd say probably not.

There are other options that might be better than spawning instances.

**AWS ECS** is an example of a managed container solution that might be a great fit.

K8s brings some other advantages, like *rolling updates* and centralised logging and performance metrics. If the scale of your single app is large, K8s might be justified.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you are not scaling beyond 100 containers, don't use K8. K8 really shines when you go up to hundreds and even thousands of containers - usually happens with some advanced, heavy data-load Machine Learning (ML) apps.

- Up to 10 containers: user Docker Swarm; comes with Docker, i.e. you do not have to install it or configure it, like K8. If you want to know more take look at [Kubernetes vs. Swarm](https://www.stratoscale.com/blog/kubernetes/kubernetes-vs-swarm-an-architects-perspective/?ban=blog_banner1).
- 10 to 100 containers:

  - Use ECS if you want to control the size of the instances, the number of containers, and some additional parameters of the ECS Service (the bag that controls how many containers are running, etc. This is the ECS equivalent of a K8 kube ...)
  - Use Fargate if you don't want to control the scaling and the underlying EC2 instances; just provide a Task Definition (as with ECS) and AWS Fargate will do the rest automatically.